# Collaborating of two threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have created a Perl script with the two threads:

1) Create `.cfg` files
2) Read those `.cfg` files

I want to accomplish that while one thread is busy making files, side by side my second thread would read those files.

Bu I am facing a problem at that moment when my second thread is created it will only read that files which are created at that moment. Can anyone give idea about accomplishing this task.

The Create threads and Reading files functions are mentioned below:

```
sub CreateThreads() {
    $threads[0] = threads->create( \&CreateCFG );
    sleep 3;
    $threads[1] = threads->create( \&ReadCFG );
}

sub ReadCFG() {

    my $id = threads->tid();

    opendir( DIR, $filedir ) or die $!;

    while ( my $files = readdir(DIR) ) {
        if ( $files eq "." || $files eq ".." ) {
            next;
        }
        else {
            my $filepath = $filedir . "/" . $files;

            if ( $files =~ m/$probename/ ) {
                my @file = split( "&", $files );

                if ( $file[3] !~~ @reportrobots ) {
                    push( @reportrobots, $file[3] );
                    my $raddr =
                        "/" . $file[1] . "/" . $file[2] . "/" . $file[3];
                    &ProbeReport( \$userdata_file, \$filepath, \$raddr );
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not combine both threads into one which would have both functions: first create file and then read it?

Comment: More detail is needed to answer this question. However I suspect the problem is that you're assuming shared variables when they're not.

Comment: Actuallly CFG files which are being created they are fetched from a source and the contents of that file are written in the file. I want that first thread should continue to make files as there will be plenty of files to create about 300-400 and I want that second thread should start after 2-3 seconds and it should start reading files.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here will be that you're not rereading the directory.

```
opendir( DIR, $filedir ) or die $!;
while ( my $files = readdir(DIR) ) {
```

Because it's not obvious, what's *actually* happening is the *first* time you call `readdir` it reads the directory, and subsequent calls just iterate that list.

That's to prevent strange things happening if - for example - I'm creating a file *in* that directory *within* my loop.

So in effect - your second thread only ever looks at that directory once. It's functionally similar to:

```
my @files = readdir(DIR); 
foreach my $file ( @files ) {
```

I would suggest that what you need is the [`rewinddir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rewinddir.html) function. Or perhaps use a `Thread::Queue` or other mechanism to pass through files in need of processing.